# Mobile : Elements in overflow scroll element ignore border radius

Tags: mobile, css

My problem has to do with how mobile browsers seem to be ignoring the border radius attribute when inside a div with overflow:scroll. Below is an example of the problem in a jsfiddle that needs to be opened in a mobile browser. As you scroll you will see that the red boxes poke out of the border-radius corners at the top and bottom of the grey element. If anyone knows of anyway to get rid of this problem, please help! Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/Thatguyhampton/LLn74/

html:

```
<div class="card scrollable">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

css :

```
.scrollable {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: overlay;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.card {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: .5em;
}

.content {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color : red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Just want to stress that I only see this on mobile browsers.

Answer (score -2):

remove the -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; and it will fix it :)